# Upgraded Ubuntu to 22.04.1 from 20.04, and my Start Menu is gone

Tags: upgrade, lubuntu, menu, interface

I upgraded to 22.04.1 LTS, from 20.4 LTS, and it works;  but I'm very distressed that the Start Menu has disappeared.  This may be due to my having Lubuntu, and upgrading Ubuntu without uninstalling Lubuntu first;  but I'm just guessing here.
In the new bar there's a 3x3 dots square icon that shows me all apps in an alphabetical order.  I used to have my start menu in the old Win95 style, but is is now gone.  It had categories such as Games, Accessories, Programming, Office, etc.  Now I have to look for apps by name.  Is there a way to recover the menu?
(Note:  In spite of using Ubuntu exclusively for a few years, I really know very little about posix;  so please keep it as simple as possible.)

Comment: Before you log in, there is a cogwheel at the lower right of the screen.  What login Desktops does it offer there?

Comment: Have you gone through system settings to adjust your preferences?  What version and flavour of Ubuntu were you using before you updated?

Comment: This change did not occur for most users. If you can elaborate on how your system or settings or add-ons might be different or unusual, that might improve your chances of getting a useful answer. Note that stock Gnome can easily place the "bar" on the left, bottom, or right -- check your "Appearance" settings.

Comment: Upgraded to 22.04.1 from what?  Are you asking about a system that was 22.04, and you just applied regular upgrades thus it upgraded to 22.04.1? or something else?

Comment: Thanks, let me answer your questions:  If this change did not occur for most users, then the problem is problably that I have lubuntu installed.  By the way, I upgraded to 22.04.1 from 20.04.  This morning I got the message that a new release was available and I clicked on Upgrade.  I have NOT gone through system settings;  I have to look for it, as I used to know thing by where they were in the start menu;  but now I don't have a start menu;  all the apps are shown alphabetically, and I'm not sure what the system settings app is called.  I'll go look for it right now.

Comment: Update:  I found Settings, and went through all of it.  Managed to move the bar from the left to the bottom;  managed to reorganize the desktop icons more the way I like them;  changed the background;  made the bar icons smaller.  Where I'm still at a loss is regarding my Start Menu button, which I had set up to look like the Win 95 menu.  It is simply gone.  I also had an icon to clear the desktop, and it's gone.  Wish to get rid of the top bar, too, if it were possible.  I'll reboot now and see if I can find the login desktops.

Comment: Ok, I remember the cogwheel before the login screen, from a long time ago;  but I don't get it anymore.  First of all, I somehow found out how to get rid of the login screen, and I got rid of it;  and I wouldn't want it back since I don't remember my password as user, anymore;  I know my admin password and that's all I ever need.  I live alone;  don't need so much security.  Or if that's not the reason I don't see the cogwheel, it may be because the screen I see on boot is the Lubuntu screen, which has no cogwheel; nothing of the sort.

Comment: Nowhere in your question do you mention Lubuntu. Don't you think that's kind of important since your problem has to do with the desktop environment? Are you still running Lubuntu, or did you install a different DE? Please edit your question- and delete these comments. Your question should be up-to-date. A new visitor to your question should not need to read a comment chain. [Edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1424918/edit) so that it's clear and complete. Ask Ubuntu is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum. If we have to guess at details your question may be unanswerable.

Comment: Done,  edited original question.

Comment: Further cleanup is needed. Again, this is not a discussion forum. Don't just tack comments to the end of the question. That's hardly an improvement. What results is a chaotic mess in a wall of text. It's confusing. You don't need to type "edit". Instead, recompose the question so that it makes logical sense from start to finish. Proofread with "fresh eyes" from the perspective of someone reading the question for the first time. Use paragraphs separating ideas presented in a logical order. Then delete the comments as they will be redundant. Confusing questions rarely get helpful responses.

Comment: Focus on one issue please. If you have multiple questions, ask them separately. Don't even bother telling us about problems that have already been solved. It's just adding extra confusion. Also, take care to ask about your actual problem. Avoid asking a question that would have an answer that doesn't solve your actual problem. For example, the answer to the yes/no question in your title is "no". That will not help you, but that's what you asked... This is called an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Ask clearly and effectively and you're more likely that someone can answer.

Comment: No problem;  thanks;  edited.

Comment: You might want to look through https://ubuntu.com/desktop/flavours and see if any of those ring a bell.  It sounds to me like you are using the Ubuntu Desktop Environment where you probably were running like Xubuntu or something like that.  Even with bypassing the login screen, the Desktop Manager (what controls the login) is still there.  To get to it, you just choose Logout from the menu instead of power down.  There you should find either a cogwheel in the lower right, or a Ubuntu logo in the upper right, or something next to your password box allowing you to choose a different one.

Comment: Ahhh, yes!, I tried logout and back in, saw the gearbox icon, and it was defaulted to Ubuntu instead of Lubuntu.  The waiting screen was showing me the lubuntu icon, so I thought I was still in lubuntu;  but was not.  Now I have the menu back and everything.  Thanks so much, Terrance!